# Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: mysql, linux

I just did a sql dump using a python script and compressed it. When I tried to restore the same in my local machine I am getting an error "Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'". But I have created a separate test database, which is empty.

Whats the problem and what would be the solution?

Comment: more info :) The DB is either not empty or your SQL dumps has hardcoded two inserts with the 1 value for PK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose your dump contains database name inside (something like `USE your_database`), so when you try to restore it you get that error.
Another condition could be a wrong dump: did you check your dump does not contain really duplicate keys?
And more: do your dump have `DROP TABLE ... IF EXISTS..` ?

Comment: I have some thing like this "CREATE DATABASE /*!32312 IF NOT EXISTS*/ "

Comment: @JeevanDongre: is there database name?